# jQuery event handler not working if not in the onLoad function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, handler

I have this script:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $($('div')).css('background-color', 'yellow')
        }, 3000)

        $('div').eq(0).draggable()      
        $('p').click(function() { 
            $(this).css('background-color', 'gray') 
        })
        $('p').click(function() { /* *** */
            console.log($(this).offset()) 
        })   
    }
</script>
```

If I move the line marked `***` below, not inside the `onLoad` function to be called, it doesn't work any more.

How can I call jQuery code after the document has loaded?
(full example page: http://pastebin.com/6zHipk4i )

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: why are you trying to move it?

Comment: Pretend it is: `$('p').click(function() { $(this).css('background-color', 'red') } )   /* *** */`
if you don't like it moving

Comment: You don't need to double-wrap this element: `$($('div'))` use this instead: `$('div')`

Comment: I had more `div` s before.. I didn't remove it, thanks

Comment: @yomh it would be better if you provided proper explanation of what you are trying to do with your code

Comment: Just trying jQuery :) @charlietfl

Comment: Then study some tutorials

Comment: I forgot I wrote I was studying on butterflies

Comment: Your code had several typos.  I have an edit pending to show the whole source as a "snippet" here (it is preferred over pastebin, etc).  Once the typos are fixed, the code seems to run.  But doing `.onload=...` is still not the jQuery way...

Comment: @J.V.A. True, if I'm right, isn't is `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @J.V.A. editing the actual code in the question to fix typos and syntax errors is not proper. It no longer exposes the original issues

Comment: I don't know how to read edits, @J.V.A.

Comment: I don't have enough "rep" to have my edits appear immediately, you'll be able to see it when it gets approved by the magic edit-approvers.

Answer (score 0):

[`onload` fires as soon as an object has been loaded](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp), whereas jQuery's `ready()` fires when it detects that all assets are loaded.
If you wanted, you could use `unload` on the body so that it executes when the page has completely loaded. However, if you're using jQuery, it's probably best to do it the jQuery way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').click(function() { console.log($(this).offset()) } );
});
```

or you will sometimes see the same thing written as:

```
$(function(){
     $('p').click(function() { console.log($(this).offset()) } );
});
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery, do it the jQuery way. Directly setting onload is asking for trouble.

Comment: @developius I fully understand that but answer doesn't reflect any of that. OP could misinterpret and put `onload` inside where you have `//code here` and wouldn't be desired affect. Answer is lacking proper explanation

Comment: now your interpretation of `onload` is completely wrong. It actually fires **after** ready event

Comment: had to downvote. `unload` concept is even worse than original description and even more incorrect

Comment: @charlietfl as you can see from this JSFiddle, jQuery's `ready()` seems to fire before the `onload`. https://jsfiddle.net/h5vhLrmk/4/

Comment: `unload` is when page is being exited and should never have even been mentioned. It's your definitions that are not accurate

Comment: Sorry, I meant `onload` instead of `unload`